# How to insert new lines after getting html tags with textContent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the picture what I am doing.

[image]

I got html tags by using

```
document.getElementById("code").textContent = document.getElementById("code-output").innerHTML;
```

code-output is from the above h1 tag to before rectangle box. "code" ID is the rectangle box that I want to display html tags that I write above.

What I want to achieve here is I want to insert new line after every html tag (bottom box). Is there any way to insert new line?

Thanks

This is the code

```js
document.getElementById("code").textContent = document.getElementById("code-output").innerHTML;
```

```css
#container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: justify;
}

#code {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  font-family: "Courier";
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="code-output">
    <h1> နိဒါန်း </h1>
    <p>
      ...
    </p>
    <p>...
    </p>
    <h2>မိမိဘာကိုလေ့လာနေတာလည်း ခွဲခြားသိရှိရမည်</h2>
    <p>
      ...
    </p>
  </div>
  <!-- code output -->

  <code id="code">
  </code>
</div>
<!-- end of container -->
```

Comment: What do you mean? the image you gave is hard to read, can you put your code in https://codepen.io/ or any other code snippet, or event give a better explanation, please?

Comment: Share your code as well

Comment: I have added my code. Thanks. I am a newbie here. So forgive me if I can't ask you question properly.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the end of your code:

```
+ "\n"
```

Like so:

```
document.getElementById("code").textContent = document.getElementById("code-output").innerHTML + "\n"
```

Comment: I get html tags from "document.getElementById("code").textContent = document.getElementById("code-output").innerHTML;